# Writing a constraint for a scheduling problem to have successive lessons with the same type

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, scheduling, or-tools

tools to generate timeTables my model is the following :

```
for l in lessons:
 for r in rooms:
  for t in timeslots:
    tables[(l,r,t)] = model.NewBoolVar('table %s/%s/%s' % (l.subject,r, t))
```

i have a certain constraint regarding friday which should have 2 arabic lessons and 2 french lessons and 1 math lesson and friday has only 5 to 6 sessions in it.

The images below shows good result for some groups and how it should be (blue section is just a pause not a session) :
[image]

[image]

And this are bad result for some groups :
[image]

[image]

[image]

So i want a constraint that garantiesthat result are similar result as the first two images which means that two Ar lessons for example should not be far from each other and needs to be sequential the same thing for Fr no problem if MATHS is between one of them.

Any helps is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: something like `model.AddBoolOr([tables["Fr", r, t-1], tables["Fr", r, t+1]]).OnlyEnforceIf(tables["Fr", r, t])`?